# python .append() replace all items of list

Tags: python, list, tkinter, append

i have a problem with my python code, i created a list named FileList and i wand to append items (files) but when i append, all items of the list is replaced by the item appended.
my code:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
import tkinter 

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Ram Explorer")
root.geometry("1024x720")
root.minsize(1024, 720)
tklist = tkinter.Listbox(root, font=("Courrier", 25)) 
FilesList = []
CurrentDir = "/"
Dirs = []

@dataclass
class Meta:
    size: int
    type: str
    name: str
    ext: str
    
class File:
    Data = ""
    Metadata = Meta(0,None,None,None)
    def Read():
        return Data
        
    def Write(NewData):
        Data = str(NewData)
        
    def Append(AppendData):
        Data = Data + str(AppendData)
    

def Actualize(Dir):
    CurrentDir = Dir
    for i in range(len(FilesList)):
        tklist.insert(i, ":   " + str(FilesList[i].Metadata.name) + "." + str(FilesList[i].Metadata.ext))
        print( str(i) + ", " + FilesList[i].Metadata.name)
    tklist.pack(expand=1, fill=tkinter.BOTH)

def NewFile(Name, extention):
    Newfile = File
    Newfile.Metadata = Meta(0, "File", CurrentDir + str(Name), str(extention))
    print(Newfile.Metadata.name)
    FilesList.append(Newfile)
    for i in range(len(FilesList)):
        print( str(i) + ", " + FilesList[i].Metadata.name)

def NewDir(Name):
    Newdir = File
    Newdir.Metadata = Meta(0, "Directory", CurrentDir + str(Name), None)
    FilesList.append(Newdir)


NewFile("Hello1", "txt")
NewFile("Hello2", "txt")
NewFile("Hello3", "txt")
NewFile("Hello4", "txt")
NewFile("Hello5", "txt")
Actualize("/")
root.mainloop()
```

and i get this:

/Hello1
0, /Hello1
/Hello2
0, /Hello2
1, /Hello2
/Hello3
0, /Hello3
1, /Hello3
2, /Hello3
/Hello4
0, /Hello4
1, /Hello4
2, /Hello4
3, /Hello4
/Hello5
0, /Hello5
1, /Hello5
2, /Hello5
3, /Hello5
4, /Hello5
0, /Hello5
1, /Hello5
2, /Hello5
3, /Hello5
4, /Hello5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you problem is with that part of code where you should create new object of class File:

```
def NewFile(Name, extention):
   Newfile = File()
   [...]
   FilesList.append(Newfile)
```

then you can append object to list. Now you have a unique class object that you can modify.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
Filelist.append("Any Value You Want")
```